# Using Microsoft AX 2012 R2 published webservice

Tags: web-services, odata, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am currently working on a pipeline program that has to interface with AX, and have just noticed that Ax does have an webservice accesible using on port 8101. 
http://localhost:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/ODataQueryService/$metadata

But how do i retrieve meaningful data out?

And am I able to extract the same data, which is stored in the ax sql db?

Comment: Have you seen https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aif/2011/08/23/odata-query-service/

Comment: @AlexKwitny Yes I have, but i  don't see a 1-1 comparison betweeen this and the sql db, and how stuff are stored in there.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Business connector could be another option for you. It basically provides you an alternative to standard services provided by AX. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-update-data-using-net-business-connector

Use this approach to write a connector to AX and then extract the data in any format you want.